# onclick event on anchor tag works in IE, but not in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, onclick

Here is relevant part of HTML code:

< a id="interest" name="interest" href="#" value=1 onclick="alert(this.value)";">Interested< /a>

the alert picks the value and shows when run in IE but shows undefined in Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1) Extra spaces in your tags. `< a>` should be `<a>`.

2) Extra quote in your `onclick` attribute. Should be `onclick="alert(this.value);"`.

3) `value` isn't a valid attribute for an anchor element.

Comment: Yeah, I gave a solution that works. But even then, I suggest the OP rethink how they're implementing this whole thing, and maybe separate out the JavaScript from the HTML.

Comment: @kennis-- implemented 1 and 2. value works in IE but not Firefox and Chrome. What would be valid attribute?

Comment: I would argue that the easiest solution (although probably not the one I would choose) would be to use a button element instead of an anchor. Buttons can have a value attribute, and since the anchor in this example isn't actually functioning as a link, you're not really changing functionality at all.

Comment: @kennis-- true. but would like to implement using anchor tag if possible.. more to do with display, space etc.

Comment: Okay. Anchor wrapped in a button with all of its styling removed: http://jsfiddle.net/jq9nW/5/

Comment: Yeah you can restyle the button to the point of making it look just like an anchor tag.

Comment: @kennis-- thanks. works perfectly in FF/IE/Chrome. only thing is link does not show up in IE. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ahh... It might be choking because it's not actually "valid" to put an anchor inside a button. I was pretty sure that all major browsers would handle it correctly, but apparently IE doesn't like it. I don't have a Windows machine handy, so I can't say for sure what's happening. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: workaround: thought I will mention achieved the link by adding a underline tag and style="color:blue" to button ..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new HTML5 data-* attribute, like so:

```
<a id="interest" name="interest" href="#" data-value="1" onclick="alert(this.dataset.value);">Interested</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This will only work in browsers that support HTML5. To access the data- attributes, you'll use  the `dataset` object attached to the element (e.g. `data-value` becomes `dataset.value`.)

Comment: works. Thanks. any suggestions for browsers which do not support HTML5

Comment: I think IE 6, 7, and 8. If support's an issue for you, then you'll probably want to find another way to go about this. Kennis' solution (using a restyled button with a value attribute) would probably work fine.